# Automatically backing up 3rd party mailservers?

Tags: backup, gmail, webmail, email

I run an internal mail server which I make nightly backups of. I want to also make backups of 3rd party email accounts such as Gmail and Hotmail. I know that both these services have access via POP/IMAP, but is there an easy way to grab messages from the commandline and back them up as with normal Maildir format files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone heard about the g[oogle debacle](http://www.engadget.com/2011/02/27/gmail-accidentally-resetting-accounts-years-of-correspondence-v/). :-)
Every service that has POP or IMAP, can be backed up by using [fetchmail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fetchmail) in Maildir-format.

This is a very nice tutorial: [wains.be](http://www.wains.be/index.php/2008/03/19/backup-your-gmail-account-in-maildir-format-using-fetchmail/)

Comment: Quick question, can I download via imap, and can I download only inbox and sent folders and exclude certain labels?

Comment: Someone wrote a script for getmail (alternative to fetchmail) that should do the trick. http://www.propertymaps.com/blog/technical/deciphering-gmail-imap-labels-with-getmail/